# How to access the response code sent to the client of an Expressjs app

Tags: node.js, express

I want to save the amount of 4XX and 5XX errors served by my server. The approach that I took was to create an express middleware to get the statusCode response

```
const fooMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.stats.totalRequestsServed += 1;

  // I want to access the status code sent to the client here
  console.log('status code', res.statusCode);
  next(null);
};
```

I'm using the code above but I'm always getting a `200` status code, even If I hardcode a `res.status(401).end()` on my route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer can be found [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175806/before-and-after-hooks-for-a-request-in-express-to-be-executed-before-any-req-a)

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    function afterResponse() {
        res.removeListener('finish', afterResponse);
        res.removeListener('close', afterResponse);

        // do smth after res.send
        console.log(res.status);
    }

    res.on('finish', afterResponse);
    res.on('close', afterResponse);

    // do smth before request eventually calling `next()`
    next();
});
```

Imho, hook is not transparency. It's need for some "special" cases.
Error handler is more better for logging 4xx and 5xx errors.

```
app.get('/smth', function(req, res, next){
   if (!smth-check)
      return next(new HttpError(401, 'Error-text')); // it's custom error class
   ...
})

app.use(function(err, req, res, next)) {
   if (err instance of HttpError)
       console.log(err.status);
   ...
});
```

About `custom error` as `HttpError` you can read *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504780/how-can-i-identify-custom-error/38506930#38506930)*

Comment: The problem with the second approach is that we are not always using next. And I like a more standalone solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic was right, you just need to call `next` *before* getting the status, so that other middlewares / your route can set the status code:

```
const fooMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.stats.totalRequestsServed += 1;
  next();
  console.log('status code', res.statusCode);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a package called [on-finished](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-finished) that manage this also adding a listener. It could be use like this:

```
const onFinished = require('on-finished');

const middleware = (req, res, next) => {

  onFinished(res, (err, res) => {
    // do smth after res.send
  });

  // do smth before request eventually calling `next()`
  next(null);
};
```